# WebView in RecyclerView Bug

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-webview, android-cardview

I implemented a Cardview with Recyclerview (from the android tutorial)
and I added a WebView to the cards, to show some HTML formatted Strings.

Now i have the same problem as here: [Bug Report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=740544&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=)

It says the problem is fixed in Chrome 61.xxx. Unfortunately my phone (LG G4 with Android 6.0) and many others
still have version 60.xx which is why my implementation is not working correctly.

How can i implement cards with webview for older phones? 
Is there a WebView alternative? Or can i disable the recycling completely? 
or is there a RecyclerView alternative for dynamic cards(content is loaded at appstart from a volley request)?

I already tried: `holder.setIsRecyclable(false);`
But the WebView still loads everytime I scroll up/down.

Comment: Use a ListView , it will work with WebView as your row item

Comment: RecyclerView recycling is not a bug it's a feature , and sometimes feature have it's drawbacks but there are plenty of workarounds for that too , but trust me you don't want to make it too complex